# question related to UITextView

Tags: iphone

I have n number of UITextview and that are added to UIScrollview.and uiscrollview is added to self.view.Now,I want that

1>If user enter text in first UITextview ,then as lenth increase os UITextview ,another UITextviews which are below it also reinitialize and maintain properly according to the size of first UITextView.inshort another UITextviews go more below then it was.

2>It should work in any of the case ,wether user presses return key after entering text into UITextView or may be not till end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in UITextView's Did Edit Begin Event Change It's Frame size and change the Position of Other UITextView...

```
myTextView.frame = CGMakeRect(myTextView.frame.origin.x,myTextView.frame.origin.y,myTextView.frame.size.width,myTextView.frame.size.height + 30)
```